# Creating array of unchangable image segments

Tags: python, arrays, image, image-processing, copy

My goal is to create a 2-dimensional array where on each position `i,j` there is the Fourier transform of the image segment with `image[i][j]` as the pixel of the upper left corner. I thought that this can be computed quite straight-forward. Assume our image is of size `m,n` and the size of the segments (or rather squares) is `s`.

```py
A = numpy.empty(shape=(m,n),dtype='object')
for i in range(m):
   for j in range(n):
      if (m-i >= s) and (n-j >= s):
         A[i][j] = numpy.fft.fftn(image[i:i+s,j:j+s]
```

Then, within a loop I want set coefficients under a certain threshold to zero:

```py
x = A[i][j]
x[np.absolute(x) <= z] = 0
```

The problem is now that it changes `A` as well but using deep-copy is to slow for a big loop. Basically `A` should not change but I need a quick copy of elements of it. How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a copy of array `A` using [`numpy.copy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html), for example:

```
x = np.copy(A)
```

This will create a copy of the array on which you can change the coefficients in `x` without changing `A`.